# Grails populate g:select from database

Tags: grails

I ran into an issue while populating domain object values on a gsp page by using a `g:select` tag.

```
<g:select name="demo" id="demo"
          value="${dm.id}"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select..']}"
          from="${dm}"
          optionValue="${dm.type}"/>
```

In my controller, I have an object which gathers values from my domain. I tried writing this object in the controller both as:

```
 def d = Demo.getAll()
```

and  `def d = Demo.list()`

Both of these returned an exception while trying to use the `g:select` tag. The error was:

**No signature of method: Demo.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[One, Two, Three, Four, Five]]**

I was able to get my code working by simply removing the `g:select` tag and writing the following in my gsp:

```
    <select name="demo" id="dm">
    <option value="">Select!</option>
    <g:each in="${dm}" status="i" var="dm">
        <option value="${dm.id}">${dm.name}</option>
    </g:each>
</select>
```

However, I would like to know how to make this work with the `g:select` tag, for my future reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues in your select:

```
<g:select name="demo" id="demo"
          value="${dm.id}"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select..']}"
          from="${dm}"
          optionValue="${dm.type}"/>
```

1. value shouldn't be looking at the collection for the id. I believe this is why you are getting your error. value should be whatever instance's id you've passed into your view.
2. optionValue doesn't required an expression.

Controller action

```
def someAction() {
   def dm = Demo.get(params.id)
   def demos = Demo.list()
   [dm: dm, demos: demos]
}
```

view

```
<g:select name="demo" id="demo"
          value="${dm.id}"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select..']}"
          from="${demos}"
          optionValue="type"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Gregg! Appreciate your help.